# MySQL copy and reverse data

Tags: jquery, mysql

I currently have a table where I have 2 columns and need to copy every row and and replicate but reversed. So ID1 goes into column 2 and ID 2 goes into Column 1.

```
COL1     COL2
-----------------
ID1   |   ID2
-----------------
ID2   |   ID1
```

Comment: What have you tried? You need to create a new table or append in this table or or replace this table?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to copy the row, swap the fields, and store the results, then you can use `INSERT ... SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (col1,col2) SELECT col2,col1 FROM yourtable;
```

If you don't want to save the resulting data you can use `UNION`

```
SELECT col2,col1 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL 
SELECT col2,col1 FROM yourtable;
```